# How to group radio buttons (from storyboard) in cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, radio-button

I'm trying to group 2 radio buttons in cocoa application.

but unlike in iOS, where you can connect the buttons with control-drag
(as shown in the picture)[image]

in cocoa application I didn't find any elegant way to do so...

any suggesting before I do something ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is my not very elegant solution -

1. define array of buttons in the class:

`NSArray* _radioButtonsArray;`

2. initialize it in viewDIdLoad:

   ```
   _radioButtonsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_radioButton1,_radioButton2,_radioButton3, nil];
   ```
3. define a **radioButtonIsPressed** method and connect it to all radio buttons as an action:

   `-(IBAction)radioButtonIsPressed:(id)sender{
      for (NSButton* btn in _radioButtonsArray){
         if (btn != sender)
             [btn setState:0];
      }
   }`

Answer (score 14):

NSMatrix used to be the solution, but it is now discouraged:

> NOTE: Use of NSMatrix is discouraged in apps that run in OS X v10.8
> and later. If you need to create a radio button group in an app that
> runs in OS X v10.8 and later, create instances of NSButton that each
> specify a button type of NSRadioButton and specify the same action and
> the same superview for each button in the group.

**If** all buttons call *the same action method* **and** *are in the same superview*, Cocoa automatically selects the clicked button  and deselects the previous button and -- no code necessary to do that.

Comment: The last part of this answer is the only relevant part: just assign the same event handler and everything works as expected.

Comment: Right you are, Ely, so I shortened the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found this (maybe not elegant):

1. control-drag a single radio button to a create an sent-action.
2. control-drag the other button(s) to the same (empty) function.

You have to hover over the function to get it connected.

Now they are grouped.

Comment: this is amazing

Answer (score 0):

I control-drag the single radio button to create an IBAction.  Then I copy/past the radio button onto the same view.  Now there are two with the same IBAction.  Cocoa treats them as grouped.